# Security issue, need to change the address bar without reloading. Can't quite seem to get there

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say we have address bar: https://blablabla.com/lessons/lesson1/?data=2&name=blahblahblah

That's all well and fine, but if the user changes 'lesson1' to 'lesson2' they suddenly get to take a lesson they never paid for.

We are using jquery and aspx technology.

I have tried using:

```
window.history.pushState({}, 'lesson1', 'blahblah');
```

This only replaces the data that comes after the '?' and not the folder path, turning it into:

```
https://blablabla.com/lessons/lesson1/blahblah
```

But they could still replace lesson1 with lesson2 and it gives them the lesson...

Likewise if they hit the 'back' arrowkey on their browser they can still see the query string before I tried to modify it.

Any suggestions would be super helpful, but they need to be cross browser and not limited to only HTML5.

We are open to the idea of downloading plugins if necessarily and also open to the idea of somehow sending them to an obfuscated link which still knows what to do, but that would be rather difficult with what we are trying to do.

Comment: Your concept is bad. You never trust client. You always need check if user is able to do preform the action on your backend or other mechanism but not by simple url link.

Comment: We only show them lessons they have paid for, but the pathing to all the lessons are the same minus the lesson name. We have code to obfuscate the data we send with the query link but I don't think we can obfuscate the whole pathing to the folders and everything.

Comment: If your user call ajax you should authorize and you know if you return any data or not. If logged user send invalid url you should return error.

Comment: They go to the location path : /lessons/lesson1/blahblah and it loads the aspx page that that lesson represents, no ajax call is present in getting them there. That's why they can just go to /lessons/lesson2/blahblah and get that lesson.

Comment: ok so you should return 403 bad page if user call url without permission to view like paid.

Comment: This security issue is known as a [insecure direct object reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References) and ***cannot*** be addressed by Javascript or any other client-side technology. You have to enforce their purchases and permissions on the server side.

Comment: @JohnWu can't I detect where the postback came from and then either allow / disallow it?

Comment: If you mean to check the referrer header, no, that can easily be spoofed. You need a server side check and some sort of secure session or token.

Answer (score 0):

If user has a login then you should check if they have purchased lession 2, if not you should return a error, for tyhis you will need to check your database to verify if this user has actually purchased the lession 2 or lession 3 etc, if you post your code we can give better answers.